# How Can I Remove a Block in JSTileMap Programmatically

Tags: swift, jstilemap

I am currently working with JSTileMap and Swift. I want my player to hit a block and have it break. does any one know how to do this? Also, how can I animate the breaking of this block? Here is my code: 
`

```
var map = JSTileMap()
var player = Player()
var previousUpdateTime = CFTimeInterval()
var walls = TMXLayer()
var hazards = TMXLayer()
var gameIsOver = Bool()
var backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    self.backgroundColor = SKColor(red: 0.4, green: 0.4, blue: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
    self.userInteractionEnabled = true

    playBackgroundMusic()
    map = JSTileMap(named: "level1.tmx")
    map.xScale = 1.3
    map.yScale = 1.3
    addChild(map)

    walls = map.layerNamed("walls")
    hazards = map.layerNamed("hazards")

    player = Player(imageNamed: "koalio_stand")
    player.position = CGPointMake(100, 50)
    player.zPosition = 15
    map.addChild(player)

}

func playBackgroundMusic() -> () {
    var error: NSError?
    let backgroundMusicURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("level1", ofType: "mp3")!)
    backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: backgroundMusicURL, error: &error)
    backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
}

func tileRectFromTileCoords(tileCoords: CGPoint) -> CGRect {
    let levelHeightInPixels = map.mapSize.height * map.tileSize.height
    let origin = CGPointMake(tileCoords.x * map.tileSize.width, levelHeightInPixels - ((tileCoords.y + 1) * map.tileSize.height))
    return CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, map.tileSize.width, map.tileSize.height)
}

func tileGIDAtTileCoord(coord: CGPoint, layer:TMXLayer) -> NSInteger {
    let layerInfo = layer.layerInfo
    return layerInfo.tileGidAtCoord(coord)
}

func checkForAndResolveCollisionForPlayer(player: Player, layer:TMXLayer){

    let indices = [7, 1, 3, 5, 0, 2, 6, 8]
    player.onGround = false

    for var i = 0; i < 8; i++ {

        let tileIndex = Int(indices[i])
        let playerRect = player.collisionBoundingBox()
        let playerCoord = layer.coordForPoint(player.desiredPosition)

        if playerCoord.y >= self.map.mapSize.height - 1 {
            gameOver(true)
            return
        }

        let tileColumn = tileIndex % 3
        let tileRow = tileIndex / 3
        let tileCoord = CGPointMake(playerCoord.x + CGFloat(tileColumn - 1), playerCoord.y + CGFloat(tileRow - 1))
        let gid = self.tileGIDAtTileCoord(tileCoord, layer: layer)

        if gid != 0 {
            var tileRect = self.tileRectFromTileCoords(tileCoord)
            if CGRectIntersectsRect(playerRect, tileRect) {
                var intersection = CGRectIntersection(playerRect, tileRect)
                if tileIndex == 7 {
                    player.desiredPosition = CGPointMake(player.desiredPosition.x, player.desiredPosition.y + intersection.size.height)
                    player.velocity = CGPointMake(player.velocity.x, 0.0)
                    player.onGround = true
                } else if tileIndex == 1 {
                    player.desiredPosition = CGPointMake(player.desiredPosition.x, player.desiredPosition.y - intersection.size.height)




                } else if tileIndex == 3 {
                    player.desiredPosition = CGPointMake(player.desiredPosition.x + intersection.size.width, player.desiredPosition.y)
                } else if tileIndex == 5 {
                    player.desiredPosition = CGPointMake(player.desiredPosition.x - intersection.size.width, player.desiredPosition.y)
                } else {
                    if intersection.size.width > intersection.size.height {
                        player.velocity = CGPointMake(player.velocity.x, 0.0)
                        var intersectionHeight = Float()
                        if tileIndex > 4 {
                            intersectionHeight = Float(intersection.size.height)
                            player.onGround = true
                        } else {
                            intersectionHeight =
                                Float(-intersection.size.height)
                        }
                        player.desiredPosition = CGPointMake(player.desiredPosition.x, player.desiredPosition.y + intersection.size.height)
                    } else {
                        var intersectionWidth = Float()
                        if tileIndex == 6 || tileIndex == 0 {
                            intersectionWidth = Float(intersection.size.width)
                        } else {
                            intersectionWidth = Float(-intersection.size.width)
                        }
                        player.desiredPosition = CGPointMake(player.desiredPosition.x + intersection.size.width , player.desiredPosition.y)

                            //(player.desiredPosition.x + intersectionWidth, player.desiredPosition.y)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    player.position = player.desiredPosition
}

func handleHazardCollisions(player: Player){

    if gameIsOver {
        return
    }

    let indices = [7, 1, 3, 5, 0, 2, 6, 8]
    for var i = 0; i < 8; i++ {
        let tileIndex = Int(indices[i])

        let playerRect = player.collisionBoundingBox()
        let playerCoord = hazards.coordForPoint(player.desiredPosition)

        let tileColumn = tileIndex % 3
        let tileRow = tileIndex / 3
        let tileCoord = CGPointMake(playerCoord.x + CGFloat(tileColumn - 1), playerCoord.y + CGFloat(tileRow - 1))

        let gid = self.tileGIDAtTileCoord(tileCoord, layer: hazards)

        if gid != 0 {
            let tileRect = self.tileRectFromTileCoords(tileCoord)
            if CGRectIntersectsRect(playerRect, tileRect) {
                gameOver(true)
            }
        }
    }
}

func breakblock(){


}





func checkForWin() {
    // 10 tiles before the map ends
    if player.position.x > ((map.mapSize.width * map.tileSize.width) - (map.tileSize.width * 10)) {
        self.gameOver(true)
    }
}

func gameOver(won: Bool){

    gameIsOver = true
    self.runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("hurt.wav", waitForCompletion: false))

    var gameText = ""

     if player.position.x > ((map.mapSize.width * map.tileSize.width) - (map.tileSize.width * 10)) {
        gameText = "You Won!"
    } else {
        gameText = "You died!!"
    }

    let endGameLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Marker Felt")
    endGameLabel.text = gameText
    endGameLabel.fontSize = 40.0
    endGameLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 1.7)
    self.addChild(endGameLabel)

   let replay = UIButton()
    replay.tag = 321
    let replayImage = UIImage(named: "replay.png") as UIImage!
    replay.setImage(replayImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    replay.addTarget(self, action: "replayGame", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    replay.frame = CGRectMake(self.size.width / 2 - replayImage!.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 2 - replayImage!.size.height / 2, 80, 30)
    self.view!.addSubview(replay)



}

func replayGame() {
    self.view!.viewWithTag(321)!.removeFromSuperview()
   self.view!.presentScene(GameScene(size: view!.bounds.size ))
    setViewpointCenter(player.position)
    map.scene!.size.height = 5000

}

func setViewpointCenter(position: CGPoint) {
    var x = returnMax(position.x, self.size.width / 2)
    var y = returnMax(position.y, self.size.height / 2)
    x = returnMin(x, (map.mapSize.width * map.tileSize.width / 2) )
    y = returnMin(y, (map.mapSize.height * map.tileSize.height / 2) )
    let actualPosition = CGPointMake(x, y)
    let centerOfView = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 2)
    let viewPoint = CGPointSubtract(centerOfView, actualPosition)
    map.position = viewPoint
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        var touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if touchLocation.x > self.size.width/2 {
            player.mightAsWellJump = true
        } else {
            player.forwardMarch = true
        }
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let halfWidth = self.size.width / 2.0
        var touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        var previousTouchLocation = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)
        if touchLocation.x > halfWidth && previousTouchLocation.x <= halfWidth {
            player.forwardMarch = false
            player.mightAsWellJump = true
        } else if previousTouchLocation.x > halfWidth && touchLocation.x <= halfWidth {
            player.forwardMarch = true
            player.mightAsWellJump = false
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        var touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if touchLocation.x < self.size.width / 2 {
            player.forwardMarch = false
        } else {
            player.mightAsWellJump = false
        }
    }
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if gameIsOver {
        return
    }

    var delta = currentTime - previousUpdateTime

    if delta > 0.02 {
        delta = 0.02
    }

    previousUpdateTime = currentTime
    player.updatePlayer(delta)

    checkForAndResolveCollisionForPlayer(player, layer: walls)
    handleHazardCollisions(player)
    checkForWin()
    setViewpointCenter(player.position)

}
```

}
`

Currently, when I run my app, my player can run forward and jump. He will hit the blocks but nothing happens. I have tried everything. Maybe the block id can be replaced by another? Any insight will be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First to retrieve your block, you use this function from JSTileMap. Map is the name of the map that u have loaded.

Since you are using JSTileMap I assume you are using Tiled since it's the best available free tool to work with JSTileMap. You can find your layer name there and be able to select or remove blocks at that layer.

```
let layer : TMXLayer = map.layerNamed("YourLayerName")
```

Node is the name of the `SKSpriteNode` which in your case is a block that you want to remove.

```
let node = layer.tileAt(star.position)
```

To animate the breaking of this block, look over to SKAction Swift Doc at the Apple website.